# Dismiss only the "Complete action using..." dialog when pressing device back button

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When we open the **About** option from the side panel and then click on any link e.g. "terms of service" then a popup appears asking to select a source as to where we want to open that link:

> [image]

When I try to close the popup using the back button on my device, this also closes the whole about page. I guess it should only dismiss the popup and let us view the about us section.

Comment: The real issue is, when you're on About page, anything that makes the SE app goes to background (whether by going to home screen, or **an app chooser dialog appears**) will close the About page. (probably `finish()` on `onPause()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

It had `android:noHistory="true"` meaning:

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".